In GitHub Pages (Jekyll), how can I change the background color of the website?
I'm currently trying to change the background color of a website I created with GitHub pages. The website is located at graspschool.github.io/ and this is the repository. I'm trying to change the assets/css/style.scss file, but my attempts have not worked so far.
I expected that changing the background-color value in the block
body {
 background-color: #FFEBEE
}

of the assets/css/style.scss file should work. However, I did add the new color, but the website hassn't changed even after it was deployed.
The current color seems to be the standard color of the Midnight theme in GitHub pages, which is indeed the theme I'm using. However, I know it is possible to override the default configurations from the theme, so I expected that changing the background color in the body should have worked.

After checking the CSS code for the midnight theme, I noticed they used the command
body {
 background: #FFEBEE
}

with background instead of background-color. This worked.

Assuming I'm looking at the correct theme, this line is setting the background to be a gradient, which is set as an image. Using background-color later on sets the background color behind the gradient, so visually it does nothing. Using background adds the color and removes the gradient, so you see what you expect to see.
